# Python - Quick Integer List Creation

Tags: python, list

Can I make a list of numbers from 1 to 6 in one line without a loop?

goal:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

Comment: there, you did it! And without a loop!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, use:

```
range(1,7)
```

that should do it.

Comment: ROFL, I'm such an idiot. I guess I'm just burnt right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`range`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range) builtin.

```
range(1, 7)
```